# changing font\color in python file using python script

Tags: python, editor

I have a python file names test.py which containes python code.

```
print "THIS IS TEST"
print "THIS IS GOOD"
print "THIS IS BAD"
```

I want to change the font\color or background of the line in any editor

```
print "THIS IS GOOD"
```

How can I do that?

If its editors specific, which editor will allow me to do such changes in file itself using code? IDLE, Eclipse, Notepad++ or any else?

Please let me know any editor and its scripting example by which I can view such changed file with changed line in it.

I DO NOT WISH TO PRINT IN TERMINAL. I NEED TO HIGHLIGHT LINE/CHANGE FONT IN ECLIPSE, NOTEPAD++ OR IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

[Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

This question will help.

An example:

```
print '\033[94m'+"THIS IS GOOD"+'\033[0m'
```

Since you referenced "notepad++", I guess you work on windows. So, try this:

[Change shell print color in python 3.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731053/change-shell-print-color-in-python-3-3-2)

```
from subprocess import call

call('color a', shell=True) #this sets the color to light green
print('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
```

Comment: I want color should be change in notepadd++ and not shell. I need to change color\font for viewing purpose in editor.