# Change The Colour Of Python Text

Tags: python, colors, passwords

I am trying to change the colour of a certain line of text. 
I have looked at other articles (including [Change shell print color in python 3.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731053/change-shell-print-color-in-python-3-3-2)) but none of the work. 
I would not like to install any external modules if that is possible.

My code:

```
from subprocess import call
call('color a', shell=True) #this sets the color to light green
print('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
```

I am using Python 3.2.3 on Linux. 
Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Try this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama.

Comment: @Dylan, what error it gives you: `/bin/sh: 1: color: not found`
? are you using linux or windows?

Comment: I am currently using Linux.

Comment: @DylanMurphy what error it shows you running your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108559/how-to-print-colour-color-in-python/48896100#48896100. CLINT or printy or sys is the module you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you are using is aimed at Windows.

You may use `termcolor`:

```
from termcolor import colored

print colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
```

---

You may use  also color formatting codes listed [here](https://www.siafoo.net/snippet/88), use them like that:

```
>>> text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
>>> print('\033[1;32m'+text+'\033[1;m')
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Output would be like:

[image]

Comment: Does not work but thanks anyway. I will still mark this as the best answer.

Comment: You have to install termcolor first: in Windows Powershell pip install termcolor, or Mac Terminal: pip3 install termcolor